# Php multidimensional array - table for each column which have same values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, html-table, usort

I couldn't find a solution for this problem. I may solve this with novice `if else` function for every specific data but, it would be very simple.

So here is my array example:

```
//I get data from mysqli

while ($recordsnumber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $records = array(
    'id' => $recordsnumber['Id'],
    'mapid' => $recordsnumber['ChallengeId'],
    'players' => $recordsnumber['PlayerId'],
    'time' => $recordsnumber['Score'],
    );
    $recordstable[] = $records;
}
```

So my data becomes like:

```
id[1] mapid[2] players[1] time[2310]
id[2] mapid[1] players[4] time[1920]
id[3] mapid[2] players[2] time[2340]
id[4] mapid[3] players[1] time[2180]
id[5] mapid[1] players[2] time[1540]
id[6] mapid[3] players[4] time[2210]
```

id is primary key in table, there maybe 10 maps, but some of them may not be played yet. There maybe 50 players but some of them may not be play yet.

First I want to make a table for each mapid, then I want to list players which have played that maps. Then I want to sort those players with best times(less is better). So it should be like this:

```
Map1
Rank-Player-Time
1.   Player2 1540
2.   Player4 1920

Map2
Rank-Player-Time
1.   Player1 2310
2.   Player2 2340
```

I'm getting player names and map names from another table. There is no problem with that. I can show times like 23:10 with wordwrap. No problem with that either.

I think something like:

```
$i=1;
foreach ($recordstable[mapid] as $table){
if ($table = $i) {
//echo $recordstable[] in lots of <tr><td> ^^
}
i++;
}
```

But it can't get which `$recordstable` row will it list. Then I know I should use `usort` to sort with best times.

So I'm stuck.

Comment: Where did your `mapid` key come from in `foreach ($recordstable[mapid]...`? (Incidentally, if you do have it as an associative array then best practice is to put quotes around `'mapid'` in that context.) It seems like you show us how you make `$recordstable` up above but then some magic occurs in between?

Comment: Oh I just made it up foreach part. I mean I don't know how to solve this exactly. I was just thinking about logic. I just want to seperate all rows which have same mapid's. Then want to sort results from time.

Comment: I think you're asking too broad a question here. Solve the things you can solve and then come back to SO and ask a specific question about how to solve something you can't figure out. What you're asking now is basically for someone to write your app for you...

Comment: Start by researching either PHP's array sorting functions or else using SQL to do your sorting for you. Then focus on creating your array (NOT table! "table" is a database term) organized by mapid. Use `echo` lots to see what various variables are holding at any one point.  Good luck!

Comment: Oh thanks anyway. I thought my question was specific actually. I just wanted to learn logic to solve this, or functions. Sorting is already easy. I don't mind it. I meant html tables with table actually ^^. I already made nice looking tables with css. And echo'ed them with unsorted arrays. It looks superb. 

I think I almost solved my question too. 2 foreach for my recordtable, and one if method can solve this.

i=1;
foreach ($recordtable as $r1 => $v1) {
 foreach ($v1 as $key => $v2){
  if ($key == 'mapid' and $v2 == i)
// echo stuff
i++;

I'm still working on it, but php is so funny.